# why getStringExtra doesn't give the proper output?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm was trying to pass some String from one intent to another. but adt says:

> Key text expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.
>   The default value  was returned.

but I'm using a String as key not what it claims!

here's the code for my first activity:

```
private int CONTACTS_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
public static final String TEXT_KEY = "text";
...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, text.getText());
startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACTS_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
```

my second activity:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEXT_KEY);
```

thanks.

p.s. here's the full stack trace:

```
03-22 14:51:32.975: W/Bundle(1248): Key text expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.  The default value <null> was returned. 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248): Attempt to cast generated internal exception: 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1085) 03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):    at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4473) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at com.saeedFri.groupsms.ContactsActivity.onCreate(ContactsActivity.java:39) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-22 14:51:33.006: W/Bundle(1248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: **"MainActivity.TEXT_KEY"** You should NEVER define `public static` fields or methods in an `Activity` - it's one of the worst practices possible in Android. Define global values either in a helper class or in the `/res/values/strings.xml`

Comment: @Squonk Tnx for your caution, will consider.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

change

```
intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, text.getText());
```

to

```
intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, text.getText().toString());
```

in first activity you need send your value, `getText` method return `Editable`, so if you want value you need use `toString()` method.

you can handle that on second class to with

```
text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEXT_KEY).toString();
```

you need use one of this two way,

Answer (score 4):

The value you are getting using `getStringExtra()` method is `SpannableString` but you are trying to put it into a `String` that's why its throwing error as below...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

You can try using `toString()` method when you are retrieving the string extra using `getStringExtra()` method as follows...

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEXT_KEY).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Got very intresting hack in my case.
I did everything as required but i missed it by intializing binding with empty/null string. i had ...

```
public static final String TITLE = "";
```

insted of

```
public static final String TITLE = "Something Here"; // Solution
```

Folled by your intent later on :-

```
String title1 = title.getText().toString();
Intent data = this.getIntent();
data.putExtra(TITLE, title1);
```

Then in receiving class -

```
String TITL = data.getStringExtra(SendingClass.TITLE);
```

Chears !